# CentOS cyberpanel PHP 8.0 zip extension

Tags: php, linux, centos, zip, cyber-panel

I'm a moodle user and recently found out that everytime i try to download a ODS file (exporting grades) it says Exception - Class "ZipArchive" not found"

it turns out that my php (version 8.0) doesn't have the zip extension installed

i tried installing the zip extension on cyberpanel(my moodle is hosted on cyberpanel CentOS 7) but i don't seems to install, when i click to install i receive this message:

```
    Loaded plugins: copr, fastestmirror, priorities
    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
     * base: atl.mirrors.clouvider.net
     * epel: mirrors.coreix.net
     * extras: mirror.dal.nexril.net
     * updates: atl.mirrors.clouvider.net
    10 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
    Package lsphp80-common-8.0.15-1.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
    Nothing to do
    PHP Extension Installed.
```

but then when i return to the extension page it says that the extension is not installed, and i still can't generate ODS files, i tried searching in about it and people said that i need to do it on terminal, i tried using cyberpanel terminal as root user with those commands:

```
    yum install php-pear
    yum install php-devel
    pecl install zip
```

then i gone to the php.ini ( i tried open it on either cyberpanel interface and on terminal) and insert the code:

```
    extension=zip.so;
```

before the "module settings" section on the file, and it still doesn't work(it sems that i have multiple versions of php installed on my cyberpanel, i tried editing php.ini on my php 8.0 directory and other versions avaliable)

its weird because on version 7.3 of php it install and work normally(it even install on the interface) and when i change the php version on my moodle to 7.3(i don't wanna use this version) it the error completely disappears, how can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below instructions for installing PHP extensions in CyberPanel for users who cannot find the desired extensions in the `Server > PHP > Install Extensions` section or in the LiteSpeed repository.

In such cases, you can use the PEAR package manager to manage PECL 17 extensions. First, change "lsphp80" to your default PHP version and run the following commands:

```
cd /usr/local/lsws/lsphp80/bin
wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
./lsphp go-pear.phar
```

Once PEAR is installed, you can install the required extension. For example, to install the latest version of the zip extension, use the following command:

```
/usr/local/lsws/lsphp80/bin/pecl install zip
```

If you need a specific version of the zip extension, you can install it using this command:

```
/usr/local/lsws/lsphp80/bin/pecl install zip-1.21.1
```

Note: Make sure to add `extension=zip.so` to your .php config

Remember to replace "lsphp80" with the PHP version you have installed as the default. This should help you install the PHP extensions you need in CyberPanel.